# Calculate the number of recursive calls to a function

Tags: java

For the following code, I want to be able to calculate the number of recursive calls to `placeQueens()` and the number of calls to `isUnderAttack()`. I tried add `int counter = 0` on the first line of placeQueens() and increment it after `queenPlaced = placeQueens(column+1);` but I keep getting some weird numbers. Is there a way to accomplish this? How efficient does my code look?

This is the output:

```
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
Queen PLACED in [3][7]
Queen Placed: 1
Queen Placed: 1
Queen Placed: 1
Queen Placed: 1
Queen Placed: 2
Queen Placed: 3
Queen Placed: 3
Queen Placed: 1
```

when I do this in `placeQueens()`

```
if (!isUnderAttack(row, column))
{
setQueen(row, column); //consider next square in column
queenPlaced = placeQueens(column+1);
counter++;
System.out.println("Queen Placed: "+counter);
//if no queen is possible in next column,
```

.

```
public class Queens
{
    //squares per row or column
    public static final int BOARD_SIZE = 8;

    //used to indicate an empty square 
    public static final int EMPTY = 0;

    //used to indicate square contains a queen
    public static final int QUEEN = 1;

    private int board[][]; //chess board

    //public int queens=0;

    public Queens()
    {
        //constructor: Creates an empty square board.
        board = new int[BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZE];

         for (int row = 0; row < BOARD_SIZE; row++) 
         {
             for (int column = 0; column < BOARD_SIZE; column++) 
             {
                    board[row][column] = EMPTY;
             }
         }
    }


    //clears the board
    //Precondition: None
    //Postcondition: Sets all squares to EMPTY
    public void clearBoard()
    {
        //loops through the rows
        for(int row = 0; row < BOARD_SIZE; row++)
        {
            //loops through the columns
            for (int column = 0; column < BOARD_SIZE; column++)
            {
                board[row][column] = EMPTY;
            }
        }   
    }


    //Displays the board 
    //precondition: None
    //postcondition: Board is written to standard output; 
    //zero is an EMPTY square, one is a square containing a queen (QUEEN).
    public void displayBoard()
    {
        //int counter = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < BOARD_SIZE; row++)
        {
            System.out.println("");

            for (int column = 0; column < BOARD_SIZE; column++)
            {
                System.out.print(board[row][column] + " ");
                 //if (board[row][column] == QUEEN)
                 //{      
                 //   counter++;
                 //}
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        //System.out.println("Number of Recursive Calls to placeQueens: " + counter);
    }



    //Places queens in columns of the board beginning at the column specified.
    //Precondition: Queens are placed correctly in columns 1 through column-1.
    //Postcondition: If a solution is found, each column of the board contains one queen and
    //method returns true; otherwise, returns false (no solution exists for a queen anywhere in column specified).
    public boolean placeQueens(int column)
    {
        if(column >= BOARD_SIZE)
        {
            return true; //base case
        }
        else
        {
            boolean queenPlaced = false;
            int row = 0; // number of square in column
            int queensRemoved = 0;
            while( !queenPlaced && (row < BOARD_SIZE))
            {
                //if square can be attacked
                if (!isUnderAttack(row, column))
                {
                    setQueen(row, column); //consider next square in column
                    queenPlaced = placeQueens(column+1);
                    //if no queen is possible in next column,
                    if(!queenPlaced)
                    {
                        //backtrack: remover queen placed earlier
                        //and try next square in column
                        removeQueen(row, column);
                        queensRemoved ++ ;
                        System.out.println("Queen Removed: "+queensRemoved);
                        //++row;
                    }
                }
                ++row;
            }
            return queenPlaced;
        }

    }



    //Sets a queen at square indicated by row and column
    //Precondition: None
    //Postcondition: Sets the square on the board in a given row and column to Queen.
    private void setQueen(int row, int column)
    {
        board[row][column] = QUEEN; 
        displayBoard();
        System.out.printf("Queen PLACED in [%d][%d]\n", row, column);
    }



    //removes a queen at square indicated by row and column
    //Precondition: None
    //Postcondition: Sets the square on the board in a given row and column to EMPTY.
    private void removeQueen(int row, int column)
    {

        board[row][column] = EMPTY;
        displayBoard();
        System.out.printf("Queen REMOVED from [%d][%d]\n", row, column);

    }


    //Determines whether the square on the board at a given row and column is
    //under attack by any queens in the columns 1 through column-1.
    //Precondition: Each column between 1 and column-1 has a queen paced in a square at
    //a specific row. None of these queens can be attacked by any other queen.
    //Postcondition: If the designated square is under attack, returns true: otherwise return false.
    private boolean isUnderAttack(int row, int column)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < BOARD_SIZE; y++)
        {
            int x1 = row - column + y;
            int x2 = row + column - y;
            if (board[row][y] == QUEEN) //possible horizontal attack
                return true; 
            if (0 <= x1 && x1 < BOARD_SIZE && board[x1][y] == QUEEN) //diagonal NW
                return true; 
            if (0 <= x2 && x2 < BOARD_SIZE && board[x2][y] == QUEEN) //diagonal SW
                return true; 
        }

        return false;
    }





    private int index(int number)
    {
        //Returns the array index that corresponds to a row or column number.
        //Precondition: 1 <= number <= BOARD_SIZE.
        //Postcondition: Returns adjusted index value

        return number -1 ;
    }



    //main to test program
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Queens Q = new Queens();
        if(Q.placeQueens(0))
        {
            //Q.displayBoard();
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Not Possible");
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "weird numbers"?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a static variable for counter so that you update the same variable while in recursive calls.

Answer (score 0):

First the counter has to be a member of the class, not a local variable.  Second of all you probably want to do it at the top of the method not within the loop.  Being in the loop is probably what is causing your "weird numbers"

Comment: can you take a look at the new code? where do i put the print statement to prevent it from printing some many times?